# Adding Functionality / behavior to a QML Slider.

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols

Is it possible to create a subclass of a QML element?

I was trying to create a custom QML slider (as opposed to the one available in QtQuick.Controls). So I wanted to look and feel to remain the same while the range itself to behave logarithmically (not arithmatically).

I know it is possible for me to define a custom slider in c++, register it with QML and then use it in QML. But I wanted to see if i could reuse the existing QML slider by creating a subclass so that I can change only what I want to change and everything else behaves the same as the QML Slider.

So. Is it possible to create a custom subclass of a QML element.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just define a new `property double logValue: Math.log(value)` in the normal slider and then use this one?

Comment: Thats a good idea for this specific problem. But in general I wanted to know if it is possible to create a subclass of a QML element.

Comment: Possible as hell, but may be useless, if customiazation-via-subclassing behavior is not there in the base item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to create a new qml file

say you name it MySlider.qml.

MySlider.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Slider {
    // anything you want
}
```

Now you can use MySlider as a new component

main.qml

```
...
...
MySlider {
}
...
...
```